# How to connect Apache Druid to Power BI without third party software's?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, druid

Can anybody please share with me the procedure to connect apache druid to power bi, many of the web tutorials I have tried but my unluck none of the implementations are work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let
  Query1 = Json.Document(Web.Contents("paste_url:paste_port/druid/v2/?pretty", 
[Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/json"], 
Content=Text.ToBinary(
"{
""queryType"": ""groupBy"",
""dataSource"": ""paste_your_table"",
""dimensions"": [""dimension1""] ,
""granularity"": ""all"",
""aggregations"": 
       [
       {
       ""name"": ""metric1"",
       ""type"": ""longSum"",
       ""fieldName"": ""metric1""
       }
       ],       
""intervals"": [ ""2020-07-27T00:00:00.000/2020-08-03T00:00:00.000"" ]
}

  
  "
)
]
)),
    totable = Table.FromList(Query1, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    expand = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(totable, "Column1", {"version", "timestamp", "event"}, {"Column1.version", "Column1.timestamp", "Column1.event"})
in
    expand
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer